# JTable and JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

I have a really huge `JTable` and I want to add scroll bars to the `JFrame` so that I can scroll to see the rest of the table instead of resizing the frame.

Problem is, when I add the table and scroll-bars, the width of the columns is shrunk to fit the size of the window. Is there any way to keep the width of the columns a constant and use a scroll-bar to view the rest of the table?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score 2):

> *"Is there any way to keep the width of the columns a constant and use a scroll-bar to view the rest of the table?"*

In this case a better solution than set a fixed (constant) width for columns is set JTable's `autoResizeMode` property to [`AUTO_RESIZE_OFF`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#AUTO_RESIZE_OFF) in order to avoid columns be auto-resized to fit the table's visible area:

```
JTable table = new JTable(15, 25);
table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
```

This snippet will produce a 15 rows and 25 columns table that will look like this (note the horizontal scroll bar):

[image: 15 rows, 25 columns table]

However this approach won't be helpful if the sum of the columns width in your table is less than the table's width. In that case it should be better to let the default [`AUTO_RESIZE_SUBSEQUENT_COLUMNS`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#AUTO_RESIZE_SUBSEQUENT_COLUMNS) policy.